# how to check location permission has been given by the user in android 6.0 for my application?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-6.0-marshmallow

My application need the location permission to allow the user to login into the application so that he need to **ON** the location in the setting.(this can be done in the android 5.1.1 and lower in case of the android 6.0 we cant do that..) Is there any chance to navigate the user directly to the permission Screen of the application in android 6.0?

Comment: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-PermissionRequest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the flow chart described in [this](http://blog.safedk.com/technology/the-marshmallows-are-coming-new-permissions-model-is-almost-here?ref=so) blog post. It's pretty straight forward and shows you how to work with the permission model and why sometimes the user won't be prompted for the permissions.

In a nutshell, the user can decline to give you this permission and then mark "never ask again". In that case, whenever you ask for that permission again, Android will simply automatically answer DENIED. You can however, when denied, display a message to the user explaining you can't go on - this section of your app cannot work properly (or at all) without this permission. It's his / her choice if to take that into consideration and grant you this permission.

Please note that badgering the user about this will probably mean they'll lose interest and patience in your app. If location is a key element of your app and they refuse to grant it to you, maybe they just don't want to use your app. It's a sad fact of life.